# C program using net-snmp does not compile

Tags: c, gcc, snmp

I have installed net-snmp 5.8 on a Ubuntu 16.0.4 machine and then I have checked the correct installation:

snmpget --version

NET-SNMP version: 5.8

Next, I am trying to write and compile my first SNMP C program example.

I have copied the one that is included as example on the tutorial from Ben Rockwood ("The Net-SNMP Programming Guide) and I have tried to compile it with the command:

```
gcc ‘net-snmp-config --cflags‘ ‘net-snmp-config --libs‘ \
> ‘net-snmp-config --external-libs‘ snmp_test.c -o snmp_test
```

As indicated in this tutorial.

When do, I get the errors:

gcc: error: unrecognized command line option ‘--cflags‘’
   gcc: error: unrecognized command line option ‘--libs‘’
   gcc: error: unrecognized command line option ‘--external-libs‘’

Then I have changed the gcc command to:

gcc `net-snmp-config --cflags` `net-snmp-config --libs` \

> `net-snmp-config --external-libs` snmp_test.c -o snmp_test

And get the error:

bash: `net-snmp-config --external-libs`: ambiguous redirect

What is wrong on the gcc call? Any comments or suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably using the wrong ticks. Use this method for command substitution, it is a bit safer:

```
gcc $(net-snmp-config --cflags) $(net-snmp-config --libs) $(net-snmp-config --external-libs) snmp_test.c -o snmp_test
```

The ticks you show here (`‘`) are the wrong ones, the ones you need are these: `` ` `` . However, I prefer the `$()` syntax, which has the additional advantage, that it is nestable.

Answer (score 0):

I have tryied **the command you tell me**:

gcc $(net-snmp-config --cflags) $(net-snmp-config --libs) $(net-snmp-config --external-libs) snmp_test.c -o snmp_test

And **I get these errors:**

/tmp/ccKrUliA.o: In function `main':

/home/jose/NETWORK_PROTOCOLS/ej_02_SNMP/snmp_test.c:29: undefined reference to `init_snmp'

/home/jose/NETWORK_PROTOCOLS/ej_02_SNMP/snmp_test.c:31: undefined reference to `snmp_sess_init'

/home/jose/NETWORK_PROTOCOLS/ej_02_SNMP/snmp_test.c:36: undefined reference to `snmp_open'

/home/jose/NETWORK_PROTOCOLS/ej_02_SNMP/snmp_test.c:38: undefined reference to `add_mibdir'

/home/jose/NETWORK_PROTOCOLS/ej_02_SNMP/snmp_test.c:39: undefined reference to `read_mib'

/home/jose/NETWORK_PROTOCOLS/ej_02_SNMP/snmp_test.c:40: undefined reference to `snmp_pdu_create'

/home/jose/NETWORK_PROTOCOLS/ej_02_SNMP/snmp_test.c:42: undefined reference to `read_objid'

/home/jose/NETWORK_PROTOCOLS/ej_02_SNMP/snmp_test.c:43: undefined reference to `snmp_add_null_var'

/home/jose/NETWORK_PROTOCOLS/ej_02_SNMP/snmp_test.c:45: undefined reference to `read_objid'

/home/jose/NETWORK_PROTOCOLS/ej_02_SNMP/snmp_test.c:46: undefined reference to `snmp_add_null_var'

/home/jose/NETWORK_PROTOCOLS/ej_02_SNMP/snmp_test.c:48: undefined reference to `snmp_synch_response'

/home/jose/NETWORK_PROTOCOLS/ej_02_SNMP/snmp_test.c:51: undefined reference to `print_value'

/home/jose/NETWORK_PROTOCOLS/ej_02_SNMP/snmp_test.c:53: undefined reference to `snmp_free_pdu'

/home/jose/NETWORK_PROTOCOLS/ej_02_SNMP/snmp_test.c:54: undefined reference to `snmp_close'

collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

**Then I have tried to add -L and -lsnmp, with this result:**

jose@jose-VirtualBox:~/NETWORK_PROTOCOLS/ej_02_SNMP$ gcc -L/usr/locallib/ -lsnmp $(net-snmp-config --cflags) $(net-snmp-config --libs) $(net-snmp-config --external-libs) snmp_test.c -o snmp_test

/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lsnmp

collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status